# EF4 how can I convert anonymous type to strong type in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

The LINQ code returns a anonymous type how can I return a strong type of "Customers"?
I am returning a anonymous type as I only want to select certain fields from the entity.

```
var customer = from c in _entities.Customers
                           join con
                           in _entities.Contracts on c.CustomerID equals con.customerID
                           where con.contractNo == number
                           select new
                           {
                               Surname = c.Surname,
                               Forename= c.Forename,
                               Address = c.Address,
                               Suburb = c.Suburb,
                               State = c.State,
                               Postcode = c.PostCode,
                               PhoneNo = c.PhoneNo
                       };
```

Thanks

Comment: You should really try to accept some of your answers, or people will be reluctant to help you in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either do

```
var customer = from c in _entities.Customers
                       join con
                       in _entities.Contracts on c.CustomerID equals con.customerID
                       where con.contractNo == number
                       select c;
```

to select the customer instances with as-is or

```
Customer customer = (from c in _entities.Customers
                       join con
                       in _entities.Contracts on c.CustomerID equals con.customerID
                       where con.contractNo == number
                       select new Customer{
                           Surname = c.Surname,
                           Forename= c.Forename,
                           Address = c.Address,
                           Suburb = c.Suburb,
                           State = c.State,
                           Postcode = c.PostCode,
                           PhoneNo = c.PhoneNo
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

to create new instances of customer with just the properties you are interested in filled out.  (provided customer class has a parameterless constructor)

Comment: I used the second LINQ query but how do I cast var customer to Customer? I only want to return one row.

Comment: @marks use `.SingleOrDefault()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` as required.

Comment: I'm getting an error on "Select" new Customer. "Cannot implicitly convert type system.linq. IQueryable<Portal.Model.Customer> to Portal.Model.Customer. 
An explicit conversion exisits( are you missing a cast) As I am creating an new Customer do I need a cast?

Comment: @marks see my edit. I have included `FirstOrDefault()` to the query. If there's going to be only zero or one result all the time, change it to `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: That worked the code compiled but I get an error:

The entity or complex type 'PortalModel.Customers' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @marks: That's because you cannot project into an entity in Linq to Entities - you should use the navigation property instead of a join or if you must use the first example

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for all customers that have any contract with a `contractNo` that matches `number` - don't use a join, instead use the EF navigation property:

```
var customers = _entities.Customers
                         .Where( c => c.Contracts.Any( x => x.contractNo == number));
```

If there is just a single (or possibly none) of these customers use `SingleOrDefault()` to just retrieve a single `Customer` entity:

```
Customer customer = _entities.Customers
                             .Where( c => c.Contracts.Any( x => x.contractNo == number))
                             .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I will look at investigating the EF navigation property.  
How do I cast var customer to Customer?

Comment: @user730381: this **is** a Customer - in the second example you can use `var customer = ...` and `Customer customer = ...` interchangeably